# Can't connect to lan using hamachi with macbook and windows 10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, macos, windows, hamachi

Trying to get a lan game going across 2 networks using hamachi. When I host the game (windows pc) and the macbook attempts to join using my hamachi ipv4 address, it is able to connect and load in before being kicked off within 15 seconds and while the computer is connected it is not able to do anything on my screen like move or look around. Now when I ping the mac's hamachi ipv4 address it comes back with around 80 latency, yet when the mac attempts to ping me using my hamachi ipv4 address it is not able to. Yet it is able to using my hamachi ipv6 address. I have tried attemping to connect using an ipv6 address in minecraft but that doesn't work.

I am able to connect to the mac's lan world using its hamachi ipv4 address no problems.

The 2 computers can ping each other and play on a lan game when on the same network no hamachi.

Thanks all

Comment: Please post your solution below as an answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can try typing this in your IP bar:

```
[lancode]:[ip address of computer that is hosting]
```